# Netbeans - how to add shared library into EAR?

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans-7, ear

I'm dealing with problem in Enterprise application in Netbeans 7.3, how to add some .jar library into EAR package to be visible as for Web application module (servlets, JSPs, etc.) and EJB module. I've tried to add this library by right clicking the enterprise project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Add Jar but it seems it doesn't work, classes from that .jar are not visible.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click your Project.
2. Select Properties.
3. On the left-hand side click Libraries.
4. Under Compile tab - click Add Jar/Folder button.

Or

1. Expand you Project.
2. Right-click Libraries.
3. Select Add Jar/Folder.

Check [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#projects-configuring).

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid it doesn't solve the problem. There's no "Libraries" item in Enterprise application project in Netbeans, only in it's Web application or EAR module. I really don't want to add the library twice into Web application and EAR module if it's possible, just to add it inside the EAR archive to be accessible for both modules.